# JPA Query with Multiple and Repeated Conditions based on object

Tags: java, sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

My use case is the following one, I need to create the following query in JPA:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column1 >= [VALUE1] AND colum1 <= [VALUE2]) OR (column1 >= [VALUE3] AND column1 <= [VALUE4]) OR (column1 >= [VALUE5] AND colum1 <= [VALUE6]) OR ...
```

And I want to use SpringBoot JPA using Repository annotation. Is there any way to define the function to allow this kind of query?

The only solution that comes to me is defining a function to query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column1 >= [VALUE1] AND colum1 <= [VALUE2])
```

that could be

```
@Query(value = "SELECT o FROM Object o WHERE o.column1 >= $1 AND o.column2 <= $2)
public List<Object> findByValues(Float value1, Float value2)
```

But this causes that I need to execute a query per each condition, and I want to retrieve the full data of all conditions in only one query.

Comment: It is not clear if the query will have a defined number of conditions and parameters or the number will be varying from call to call. If the query has a constant form then it can be defined as a JPARepository method. If not then it can be build dynamically with CriteriaBuilder.

Comment: it will change depending on each call. Can you provide an example of CriteriaBuilder?